# Couldn't connect hdfs from local machine

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm writing a simple program to read/write data from HDFS. I'm not able to connect hdfs installed in my remote machine from my local machine. I'm getting the following exception

```
18/08/19 16:47:45 DEBUG lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginSuccess with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(sampleName=Ops, always=false, about=, type=DEFAULT, value=[Rate of successful kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], valueName=Time)
18/08/19 16:47:45 DEBUG lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginFailure with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(sampleName=Ops, always=false, about=, type=DEFAULT, value=[Rate of failed kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], valueName=Time)
18/08/19 16:47:45 DEBUG lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.getGroups with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(sampleName=Ops, always=false, about=, type=DEFAULT, value=[GetGroups], valueName=Time)
18/08/19 16:47:45 DEBUG impl.MetricsSystemImpl: UgiMetrics, User and group related metrics
18/08/19 16:47:45 DEBUG security.Groups:  Creating new Groups object
18/08/19 16:47:45 DEBUG util.NativeCodeLoader: Trying to load the custom-built native-hadoop library...
18/08/19 16:47:45 DEBUG util.NativeCodeLoader: Failed to load native-hadoop with error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hadoop in java.library.path
18/08/19 16:47:45 DEBUG util.NativeCodeLoader: java.library.path=/Users/rabbit/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
18/08/19 16:47:45 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/08/19 16:47:45 DEBUG security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback: Falling back to shell based
18/08/19 16:47:45 DEBUG security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback: Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping
18/08/19 16:47:45 DEBUG util.Shell: Failed to detect a valid hadoop home directory
java.io.IOException: HADOOP_HOME or hadoop.home.dir are not set.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHome(Shell.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:734)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2748)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2740)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368)
    at com.rabbit.hdfs.io.ReadFileDataToConsole.main(ReadFileDataToConsole.java:22)
18/08/19 16:47:45 DEBUG util.Shell: setsid is not available on this machine. So not using it.
18/08/19 16:47:45 DEBUG util.Shell: setsid exited with exit code 0
18/08/19 16:47:45 DEBUG security.Groups: Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback; cacheTimeout=300000; warningDeltaMs=5000
18/08/19 16:47:45 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: hadoop login
18/08/19 16:47:45 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: hadoop login commit
18/08/19 16:47:45 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: using local user:UnixPrincipal: rabbit
18/08/19 16:47:45 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: UGI loginUser:rabbit (auth:SIMPLE)
18/08/19 16:47:46 DEBUG hdfs.BlockReaderLocal: dfs.client.use.legacy.blockreader.local = false
18/08/19 16:47:46 DEBUG hdfs.BlockReaderLocal: dfs.client.read.shortcircuit = false
18/08/19 16:47:46 DEBUG hdfs.BlockReaderLocal: dfs.client.domain.socket.data.traffic = false
18/08/19 16:47:46 DEBUG hdfs.BlockReaderLocal: dfs.domain.socket.path = 
18/08/19 16:47:46 DEBUG retry.RetryUtils: multipleLinearRandomRetry = null
18/08/19 16:47:46 DEBUG ipc.Server: rpcKind=RPC_PROTOCOL_BUFFER, rpcRequestWrapperClass=class org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$RpcRequestWrapper, rpcInvoker=org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker@12405818
18/08/19 16:47:46 DEBUG ipc.Client: getting client out of cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@7ff2a664
18/08/19 16:47:46 DEBUG shortcircuit.DomainSocketFactory: Both short-circuit local reads and UNIX domain socket are disabled.
18/08/19 16:47:46 DEBUG ipc.Client: The ping interval is 60000 ms.
18/08/19 16:47:46 DEBUG ipc.Client: Connecting to /192.168.143.150:54310
18/08/19 16:47:46 DEBUG ipc.Client: closing ipc connection to 192.168.143.150/192.168.143.150:54310: Connection refused
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:700)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1463)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1382)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:1165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.fetchLocatedBlocksAndGetLastBlockLength(DFSInputStream.java:268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSInputStream.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.<init>(DFSInputStream.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:1318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:289)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:289)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:764)
    at com.rabbit.hdfs.io.ReadFileDataToConsole.main(ReadFileDataToConsole.java:29)
18/08/19 16:47:46 DEBUG ipc.Client: IPC Client (775931202) connection to /192.168.143.150:54310 from rabbit: closed
18/08/19 16:47:46 DEBUG ipc.Client: stopping client from cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@7ff2a664
18/08/19 16:47:46 DEBUG ipc.Client: removing client from cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@7ff2a664
18/08/19 16:47:46 DEBUG ipc.Client: stopping actual client because no more references remain: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@7ff2a664
18/08/19 16:47:46 DEBUG ipc.Client: Stopping client
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Call From rabbit/127.0.0.1 to 192.168.143.150:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:1165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.fetchLocatedBlocksAndGetLastBlockLength(DFSInputStream.java:268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSInputStream.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.<init>(DFSInputStream.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:1318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:289)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:289)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:764)
    at com.rabbit.hdfs.io.ReadFileDataToConsole.main(ReadFileDataToConsole.java:29)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:700)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1463)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1382)
    ... 24 more
```

I took this [link](https://www.folkstalk.com/2013/06/write-file-data-to-hadoop-hdfs-java.html) as my reference.I'm breaking my head to debug further. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Can someone please help me to get this sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the ip address `192.168.143.150` to `/etc/hosts` like

```
192.168.143.150 192.168.143.150


127.0.0.1 localhost
```

This helped me to get resolved. Thanks :)

Comment: `192.168.143.150`  should be followed by the output of `hostname -f`, otherwise you don't need to mention it twice... However, this has nothing to do with the error in your question

Comment: yeah, but without adding this at the remote machine - i couldn't connect from my local machine.

Comment: From the error 1) `HADOOP_HOME` wasn't defined 2) there's some other network problem not allowing you to access the port of that IP. Simply adding an IP address to your hosts file doesn't really do anything

Comment: @cricket_007 : I added `HADOOP_HOME` to my system variable in my local machine - and added the ip in `etc/hosts` in my remote machine - and restarted hadoop - It helped me...

Comment: Okay, then the solution was probably restarting Hadoop if that allowed you to access a process that was previously stopped

Comment: Okay @cricket_007. But I did restart n number of times previously but it was of no use :(

Comment: Alright, well, at least you got it working. I'm just letting you know that there's probably something else you did that actually fixed it